# Invalid column name. The name was never implemented in the code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a simple program which I'm setting up to be used with unit testing. For some reason, Entity Framework is yelling at me with the following error: `Invalid column name 'Author_Id'.`

The problem is I do not have a column named Author_Id, not in the project, not in the Models and not in the tables on the database. For some reason, it's adding the `_Id` part to the end of what I search for.

Example: If I set it to search for `Author` I get `Author_Id`. `AuthorId` becomes `AuthorId_Id` and `Author_Id` turns into `Author_Id_Id`.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. I did a search through the entire solution and nothing was found.

It tells me that my error is here:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    var books = db.Books.Include(b=>b.AuthorId);
    ViewBag.AlbumCount = books.Count();
    return View(books.OrderBy(b => b.Author.Id).ToList());
    //^^^^ Return is supposed to be doing the error. Fetching Name or 
}
```

My Author Model is this:

```
public class Author
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Author")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date of death")]
    public DateTime? DateOfDeath { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

My Book model is this:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select author")]
    public Author AuthorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Publication date")]
    public DateTime? PublicationDate { get; set; }

    public float? Edition { get; set; }

    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Would you share Fluent Api too ?

Comment: I think its looking for the field Author_Id , in the book model, because it looks like your trying to use it as a foreign key. comment out the Author property and the AuthorId property in book. I bet it works then.

Comment: @Dylan But it is supposed to be a foreign key.

Comment: @Rainman What is Fluent Api?

Comment: @Dylan Changing `AuthorId` to `Author_Id` just repeats the `Author_Id_Id` problem. All I get is `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Author_Id'.`

Comment: You should configure navigation properties with Fluent Api or annotations. I couldn't see ForeignKey annotation. So, would you check the Context OnModelCreating method.

Comment: Side note. Are your books all single author?

Comment: I do not have any book yet. It's showing the error on the GET version of create method

Comment: @AlexKudryashev this model is not many-to-many relationship, so by design this model supports only one author per book.

Comment: Pretty sure navigation properties need to be `virtual` i.e. `public virtual Author Author { get; set; }`

Comment: you may want to try to map the FK to the navigation property. With this mapping, EF has no idea AuthorId is supposed to be the FK to Author, so it creates a new FK to map the navigation property called Author_Id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two Navigation Properties, instead of one Navigation Property and one Foreign Key Property.

Shouldn't this:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select author")]
    public Author AuthorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Publication date")]
    public DateTime? PublicationDate { get; set; }

    public float? Edition { get; set; }

    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

be

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select author")]
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Publication date")]
    public DateTime? PublicationDate { get; set; }

    public float? Edition { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

?

Comment: This would be the closest to the solutions for the problem. I also basically didn't have a valid db mapping. A lot of mistakes

Comment: Nice catch! I didn't see the wrong type of `AuthorId` (`Author` instead of `int`).

Answer (score 2):

The `Include` method is for loading related entities, not single columns (like `AuthorId`). Include the navigation property instead.

Replace

```
var books = db.Books.Include(b => b.AuthorId);
```

by

```
var books = db.Books.Include(b => b.Author);
```

Note: `authorId` is loaded anyway, as it is simply a column in the books table.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys. I was kind of trying to use code first and database first at the same time. I had to remove the old tables and recreate them with migrations. Then I also had 2 different dbContexts. One for Identity and one for me. Also, relations were all messed up. Anyway if someone has a similar problem check your relations. And use database first or code first. Don't mix them like I did.